# add data from form into query

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm building a very basic html website for use on a smartphone, which would look something like this

```
<body>
Some Text
<form name="input" action="query.php" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
```

Then in the query.php I have this

```
select ProductName, PalletSpace, Quantity, TransactionDate from Table1
having Table1.PalletSpace='B005E';
```

How can I link the two up so that the text typed into the search box is inserted into the query (where it says B005E?)?

EDIT:
query.php now contains this:

```
<?
$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";



$con = mysqli_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ProductName, PalletSpace, Quantity, TransactionDate FROM ProductTrans
WHERE ProductName = ($_REQUEST["search"])");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Product Code</th>
<th>Pallet Space</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['PalletSpace'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TransactionDate'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

query.php and the html file (which is still the same) are in the same directory. However, when I try a search, it gives me this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/u921305435/public_html/query.php on line 11
```

Comment: You may try this .
select ProductName, PalletSpace, Quantity, TransactionDate from Table1
having Table1.PalletSpace="$_REQUEST['search']";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I should do this, but in case anyone is stuck on the same thing

search.html ended like this

```
<html>
<body>
Some Text
<form name="input" action="query.php" method="GET">
Search: <input type="text" name="search">
<br /><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

query.php like this

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Search results</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$query = $_GET['search'];

$min_length = 0;

if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length then

    $query = htmlspecialchars($query); 

    $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);

    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ProductTrans
        WHERE (`ProductName` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`PalletSpace` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

        echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Product Code</th>
    <th>Pallet Space</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['PalletSpace'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['TransactionDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    }
    else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results";
    }

}
else{ // if query length is less than minimum
    echo "Minimum length is ".$min_length;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your php code you can use `$_REQUEST["search"]` to get the input the user gave in the textbox.

Comment: So where do I put that? Where it currently says B005E?

Comment: Yes, you place it where it currently says 'B005E' in your query.